# Make my APK from a known source

Tags: google-play, apk

How can I make my APK file considered a known source when installing it?

Is uploading my APK into Google Play is enough to be considered a "known source" or are the 
any other actions I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, uploading your APK onto the Google Play store will work. Installations through the Google Play Store are considered through a "known" source. Unknown sources would be installations through [sideloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sideloading) or third party marketplaces. Refer to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/open-distribution.html) for installing applications from other sources.